# Issue with input form and looping through an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, frontend

I'm trying to solve this challenge for a FreeCodeCamp challenge and I'm running into an issue I have no idea how to solve.

This is a link to the Codepen where I've put all my code: [Click here](https://codepen.io/Ashkya/pen/bWojwJ)

Basically the issue is with the last function, the one used to search through the list of users.
I've made so that whenever the value of the search form changes, it loops through the users object and hides the ones that are not containing any of the characters inserted.

The whole code works just fine, specially since I'm `console.log()`-ing all the variations of the variables in the function, but on the front end side it stops after two iterations. For example, if I search for Nelari, the code hides most of the users after I insert `N` and even more users are hidden when I type `e`, but after these 2 iterations it stops. On the console it goes on and gives back the right result until the very end but on the front site it just stops.

Besides that, I've noted that even tho some of the showing users are correct in terms of what I've searched for, it keeps some of those that don't contain any of the characters I've put in.

For simplicity I'll put the function code here too:

`

```
// SEARCH FORM 
 window.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
        var searchQuery = $("input").val().toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Z0-9_]/ig, "");
    search(Acc, searchQuery);   
    }, false);

function search (accounts, what) {
    console.log(what);
    if (what.length > 0) {
        Object.keys(accounts).forEach(function(key) {
            var IDD = "." + key;
            console.log(IDD)
            accQuery = key.toLowerCase();
            console.log(accQuery);
            if (accQuery) { 
                if ( accQuery.indexOf(what) >= 0 ) {
                    $(IDD).css({"display": "block"});   
                    console.log("FOUND!");
                };
                if ( accQuery.indexOf(what) == -1 ) { 
                    $(IDD).css({"display": "none"});
                    console.log("NOT FOUND!");
                };
            };

        });
    }
    else if ( what.length < 1 ) {
        Object.keys(accounts).forEach(function(key) {
            var IID = "." + key;
            $(IID).css({"display": "block"});
        });
    };
};`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I saw in your code you're selecting by class the elements to hide. The key of the accounts could be with uppercase and the li classes are in lowercase. As the CSS selectors are case sensitive (http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/casesensitivity) it doesn't find the correct element to hide. If you use accQuery to get the element instead of the key it will work.

```
   accQuery = key.toLowerCase();
   console.log(accQuery); 

   var IDD = "." + accQuery ;
   console.log(IDD)
```

Comment: You my friend are a genius, I can't believe I didn't noticed that! Thanks a lot!